# Which English word for the person who helps travellers while travelling?

Tags: single-word-requests

While travelling, a person joins travellers to help, explain and introduce the place we travel. What is the English word for that person?

Comment: You should include a sample sentence to demonstrate how the word would be used.

Comment: Much depends on ***how*** you travel. If you're travelling by plane, the person who looks after your needs will be an ***air hostess*** or ***flight attendant***. A century or two ago, when the wealthy would take *The Orient Express* for their sightseeing travels, the guy who looked after them on the train would be a ***porter***.

Comment: Eg:-    ( *The one who helps while travelling* )explained the history of that place.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of related roles

A **guide** or **tour guide** or more formally **tourist guide** (as mentioned) takes groups of tourists around, talking knowledgeably about history, architecture, etc. They may escort a tour group on their travels through multiple destinations, or just provide short tours of a specific city, area, or building. ([Career information](https://nationalcareers.service.gov.uk/job-profiles/tourist-guide))

A **holiday rep** (short for **representative**) is a related job which involves providing assistance and possibly entertainment to holiday-makers and maybe arranging coach trips and transfers, but doesn't require any deep historical or art-historical knowledge. It's often associated with package holidays, beach holidays, etc. ([Career info](https://www.prospects.ac.uk/job-profiles/holiday-representative))

Another related job is a **concierge**, who usually is based in one place such as a hotel or a specialist concierge service, and who tells people the best places to go for whatever they want, but doesn't accompany them. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concierge))

A **tourist information officer** does something similar to a concierge but works out of a (often publicly-funded) tourist information office and serves all visitors not just those who've paid.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: tourist guide sounds non English to me....

Answer (score 2):

This is the job of a tour guide (American English) or (less commonly used in British English) [tourist guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_guide). Just *guide* may work too.

> a person who takes people on trips through an area and explains the interesting details about it

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tour%20guide))

It can be used both for people who guide an entire multi-day trip for a fixed group of people, as well as guiding a 'random' group of visitors to a single location for a few hours.

Comment: These days the term "tour guide", or sometimes just "guide", is more usual in the UK than "tourist guide". I can't remember ever hearing anyone being described as a "tourist guide" in the last 50-60 years.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite here is the eponymous **cicerone.**

> person who conducts sightseers; guide.

[Dictionary.com]

Comment: Yes that term is available, but to avoid misleading the learners of English who may come to this page, it should be said that it has a rather old-fashioned ring. It is a term that one expects to see in a novel set in the 19th or early 20th century rather than in ordinary present-day communication.

Answer (score 0):

To the terms already offered in the other posted answers, one should add ***courier***. The term is, however, used in this sense only in British English; the speakers of American English are likely to find this use of it confusing. A courier works for a company that sells package holidays and represents it 'on the ground'; the term would thus not be used for the guides that work for local businesses.